# Eclipse won't compile into bin , Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, program-entry-point

I've been using eclipse to program in java for a month or two now. I have a package boats, within it many classes all run from the main class boatGame. Eclipse has built and rebuilt the numerous iterations of my program until today, when it seems to have stopped cooperating. When I hit run, I get the error,

```
Error: Could not find or load main class boats.BoatGame
```

When I investigated, I found that the Bin folder is empty and devoid of the replicated source file components as .class files. An unrelated program would run from eclipse, but when I deleted it's bin file components, it too gave me the same error, with its bin folder also remaining completely empty.

My default output folder is boats/bin, and a search of my computer didn't yield any .class files that may have been built in the wrong place. I have also deleted and re-installed both eclipse and JDK. Does anyone have any pointers as to how I could start building programs within eclipse again?

Comment: what is the output folder, `right click on project> properties > java build path > sources ` ?  is there any compilation erorr in your code  check problem view ?

Comment: The output folder was boats/bin . I even put a syntax error in the code, and it was clear that it wasn't even trying to compile, since I didn't get any warnings about the error.

Comment: Do you select project as Build Automatically under Project menu?

Comment: Yep. I haven't changed that since I first ran eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs with me too. Here is the solution:

**1. Open the folder in which the .java files are present of the project boats (boats/src).**

**2. Now, go to eclipse and make a new project. (boatsA or boatsB, whatever you like).**

**3. Make the same(name) classes as in boat (it may take time).**

**4. Copy the text in each .java file and paste it in respective classes.**

**5. Save all classes.**

**6. Run it!**

I am 100% sure that it will run.

Though in your case, it may work.

Comment: That worked for me. I just wish I knew what actually caused this error in the first place so I could avoid it in the future!

Comment: Don't think about that error! If it is solved then what to think about other then your project ;)

Comment: I've had this happen frequently and it was a permission issue for eclipse. Deleting and recreating the bin folder followed by a clean build fixed the workspace. Sometimes using a clean start for Eclipse also fixes it. (But don't worry too much, it seems fairly rare)

Answer (score 2):

I ran refactor/rename on the project name and then renamed it back to the original and it fixed the problem.